# The "unread message" icon doesn't disappear without reload

Tags: bug, top-bar, stackexchange.com

On StackExchange.com, when I click the red icon with a number of unread messages, it doesn't disappear when I later close the list of the messages. It seems to disappear in other SE sites. (The same happens to the Achievements).

[image: Unread messages]

Comment: This also happens with the achievements number.